# How to fix GC error in Mac Common Lisp 5.0?

Tags: garbage-collection, lisp, common-lisp, mcl

I'm fairly new to Lisp, and I'm trying to run an algorithmic music application on the original MCL 5.0 (not the RMCL version). The program works by incrementally inputting textual representations of music, and learning from the user via an association net. Unfortunately, shortly after I begin inputting the text, I begin to see the GC icon flash. The more text I input, the longer the GC will appear, until finally it will last so long that the application will crash. I've been talking with the creator of this application, and he's never had this problem. Any ideas as to how I might fix this? Perhaps somehow altering my MCL's GC preferences?

On a side note, when I input the text and the GC icon is flashing, in Activity Monitor it shows MCL using around 90% of my CPU's processing power, but not much RAM.

Answer (score 1):

MCL on what OS and Mac?

It could be that MCL starts up with too little memory. Possible reasons: it is configured for too little memory, the Mac has too little free memory for some reason.

```
(room t)
```

shows details about the available memory.

It can also be that the program takes up too much memory when running. Reasons for that: it is not compiled or the available memory is too small.

Generally I would propose to use the MCL user mailing list for these questions.

Send a message with the text 'help' in the body to *info-mcl-request  @  digitool.com* (remove the spaces). You will get a message how to subscribe. The actual mailing list is  *info-mcl   @   digitool.com* (again without the spaces).